# Setting the color of the home bar area of the mobile screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, colors

I have tried options for setting the safearea by wrapping it in a container and several other background options but they do not extend further enough to allow the very last section of the screen to be adjusted.

[image: This lower section is black and I would like it to be white]

How can this section of the screen be adjusted in Flutter so it blends in with the rest of the UI. Please note that the UI is a webview set to fill the safearea. My priority is for Android devices.

Comment: What is your expected result? Can you provide an image?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap Scaffold with SafeArea widget. In the SafeArea widget, set bottom:false. And Wrap SafeAre widget with Container.

```dart
class PostsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const PostsPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: SafeArea(
        top: false,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: const Placeholder(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]